# India visa expiring 2 days after arrival

Tags: visas, india, visa-extensions, denial-of-entry, visa-expiration

I finish my last university exam on the 15th in the UK, so I'm flying to Pune via London-Delhi to see my family (where my father is employed and whom I'm dependent on) on the 15th arriving on the 16th.

My visa expires on the 18th (a Monday), so I am scheduled to visit the local FRO for the renewal process on the 18th itself (earliest possible date). It is a stay visa, not a tourist one. I have to renew annually as per regulations.

Would there be any issues in entering the country so close to the visa's expiry?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Ministry of Home Affairs](https://boi.gov.in/content/requirments-extension-visa), that's cutting it a bit close

> **Extension requirements for foreign national**:
>
> Foreigners must submit application for extension of residential permit/visa at least 60 days before the date of expiry of respective residential permit/visa.
>
> **Late Renewal of Residential Permit**:
>
> A foreigner who has delayed for renewal of RP, on application, if delay is  condoned will be charged a penalty in Indian currency equivalent to US $30/- for late renewal.

You may want to see whether you can renew through the [e-FRRO online portal](https://indianfrro.gov.in/eservices/home.jsp#) or book an appointment at your local FRRO office (and have confirmation with you when you arrive at the border).